# How to get email address with VBA based on windows login name?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ldap

How can I use VBA to get the email address of users on my network based on their Windows user name?

I have a log file that contains the UserName of everyone who launched this Access database.  The username was generated from `Environ("USERNAME")` when they launched the database.  I need to send an email to all recent users.

I don't need it to return the current users email address, and I don't need the code to send email.

I was wondering if it was possible using LDAP, but the example I have only works for the current logged in user.  Is there another way?

```vb
Function GetEmailAddress(Optional strUserName As String = "") As String
' Get user's email address from LDAP

    Dim sysInfo         As Object
    Dim oUser           As Object

    If strUserName = "" Then
        ' No name was passed in.  Get it for the current user.
        strUserName = Environ("USERNAME")
    End If

    ' How I can I use strUserName to get the email address?
    ' The LDAP query below only works for the current logged in user.

    Set sysInfo = CreateObject("ADSystemInfo")
    Set oUser = GetObject("LDAP://" & sysInfo.UserName & "")

    Debug.Print "Display Name: "; Tab(20); oUser.Get("DisplayName")
    Debug.Print "Email Address: "; Tab(20); oUser.Get("mail")
    Debug.Print "Computer Name: "; Tab(20); sysInfo.ComputerName
    Debug.Print "Site Name: "; Tab(20); sysInfo.SiteName
    Debug.Print "Domain DNS Name: "; Tab(20); sysInfo.DomainDNSName

    GetEmailAddress = oUser.Get("mail")

    Set sysInfo = Nothing
    Set oUser = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Have a table of users with Username and Email fields. If your organization has an email address structure that includes the username, build the address dynamically. Might be able use Outlook automation to search address book for address associated with a user's full name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I use the following function, though there are many possibilities.

```
Public Function GetMailAddress(strUsername As String) As String
    Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
    Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    cn.Open "Provider=ADsDSOObject;"
    cmd.CommandText = "<LDAP://dc=MyCompany,dc=intranet>;(&(objectCategory=User)(CN=" & strUsername & "));mail;subtree"
    cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
    Set rs = cmd.Execute
    GetMailAddress = rs.Fields(0).Value
End Function
```

You need to fill in the valid DC values for your LDAP server, of course.

Comment: I was able to get your solution working after changing `CN=strUserName` to `sAMAccountName=strUsername`.  I also had to add a reference to `Microsoft AcitveX Data Objects x.x`.  It only works on employees in our US office.  It did not work for users on the europe domain even when I modified the `DC=` for it.  It may just be that I'm unable to query across the domain.  Would any of the 'other possibilities' be more likely to work globally?

Comment: First, we'd need to diagnose the problem. You might, for example, just not have the rights to query the LDAP server (which seems likely to be because you're not logged-in on it).